# CDT 8.5 for Eclipse Luna does include the Microsoft Visual Studio key map

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, key, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse Luna 4.4 and the installed CDT 8.5 and noticed the Visual Studio key map option was not available. I finally installed an older version and the option was available. Can anyone else verify this finding? I didn't find any mention of this on the CDT site. Thanks.

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 0):

Use Key Assist.. Ctrl+Shift+L

Or try.
Not completely obvious!
First you have to install the C++ Development SDK (Help => Install new software => C++ => C++ Development Tools) and then you go to Preferences => General => Keys and select Microsoft Visual Studio as Scheme.